# Ontology where the same word has different meaning in different contexts?

Tags: ontology, protege, ontology-mapping

Are there any example ontologies where the same word has different meaning in different contexts?

For example, when building an ontology for a large company, it is not uncommon for different departments and systems to have a different definition and understanding of common words like "customer", "account", etc.

Is there a generally accepted way to model this in Protege that preserves the original words in their context, while also introducing a layer of disambiguating words for enterprise use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem we encounter often in the biological community. I.e., the concept Eye is very dependent on the context, i.e. human eye vs fish vs spider eye etc. You can see a search for eye on the [Ontology Lookup Service (OLS)](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/ols/search?q=eye) and the results it return for eye from different ontologies. Disclosure: I am responsible for this tool.

1. Provide an IRI for your concept. This IRI should be similar to a surrogate key for your concept. I.e., instead of giving your Account concept an IRI like http://MyBusiness/someBusinessContex/Account you give it an IRI like http://MyBusiness/someBusinessContex/Context0000001. For the Eye concept the IRI for a human eye is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/NCIT_C12401 and for an insect it is http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/SIBO_0000086.

I explain in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58941918/why-is-a-code-instead-of-the-string-used-in-rdf-for-an-object) the reason for using "surrogate keys".

2. Assign a context specific label and definition to your concept. You can use `rdfs:label` for label and `rdfs:comment` or `skos:definition` for definition.
3. You may find that you need alternatives for you concept. I.e. may be you refer to customers also as members. In this case you can use `skos:altlabel` to provide alternative names for your concept and `skos:preflabel` to define a preferred label.

So how does this work? For user interfaces you make use of  `rdfs:label`/`skos:preflabel` and `rdfs:comment`/`skos:definition` for display purposes. From a data integration perspective you use the IRI.